# Viewport position shift - triggered by scroll to top

Tags: javascript, css, ios, reactjs, next.js

My viewport is shifting up (above the screen), triggered by an attempt to scroll to top.

Two videos:

1. **Twitter bug**:

When I click the search icon on the bottom nav bar, the top nav and bottom nav shift up; however, the page underneath does not move. The result is a distorted viewport.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/assets/51684334/a41fb19a-655c-4a62-babb-8f5e0a474121

2. **My app (same bug)**:

When I click My Site (middle icon on the bottom nav bar), the top nav and bottom nav shift up; however, the page underneath does not move. Again, the result is a distorted viewport.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/assets/51684334/60b4fb8f-462b-4a52-8077-271f7c353525

My hunch is that this is related to iOS's 100vh bug, but I really have no idea! Any help or thoughts would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: (Not clear from the videos what is the exact manipulation - since the missing pointer handler) One pretty quick idea is to use the newer `100dvh` (instead of `100vh`) - https://caniuse.com/?search=dvh

Comment: I clicked the button on the bottom nav. I have tried dvh, to no avail.

Comment: Without knowing what your CSS is, there is no way to help. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask); in particular the part about providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Stack Overflow has tools to provide an [inline live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).